# How do I put an image next to a table in wordpress without css?

Tags: wordpress, image, html-table

This is my code, but the image is above the table, and I want them side-by-side:

```
<div style="float:left;">
    <img src="http://localhost/test1/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/GautengNew-1.gif"; alt="" width="500" height="538" />
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
    <table style="margin-left: 10%; float: top;" border="1" width="440"> 
        <tbody>
        <!-- Table Rows Here -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

See current and desired output:

[image: align a table and an image]

Comment: You should put your code as text in your question, with the image split into two: "Current Output" and "Desired Output".

Comment: If you use floats, you need to make sure that the overall width of each side equals 100% (i.e. 40% and 60%). Otherwise one will be beneath the other.

Comment: Thanks for the posting advice steve - my first ever post here - I have never designed nor attempted to design a website before - I'd say today is my 5th day.

Comment: <div class="alignnone size-full wp-image-161"><div style="float:left"><img src="http://localhost/test1/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/GautengNew-1.gif" alt="" width="500" height="538" /></div>



<table style="margin-left: 10%; float: top;" border="1" width="440">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;" width="110">

Comment: Hi Ibrean I posted my code - can you show me how please. I am a newbie at wordpress (for website design for that matter)...

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are using `<div>` rather than `<span>` tags. If you must use `<div>` you could either set the second one to `float:right` or add to their style - `display: inline-block;`.

Something like this:

```
<span style="float:left;">
    <img src="http://localhost/test1/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/GautengNew-1.gif"; alt="" width="500" height="538" />
</span>
<span style="float:left;">
    <table style="margin-left: 10%; float: left;" border="1" width="440">
         <tbody>
         <!-- Table Rows Here -->
         </tbody>
    </table>
</span>
```

or this:

```
<div style="float:left;display:inline-block;">
    <img src="http://localhost/test1/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/GautengNew-1.gif"; alt="" width="500" height="538" />
</div>
<div style="float:left;display:inline-block;">
    <table style="margin-left: 10%; float: left;" border="1" width="440"> 
        <tbody>
        <!-- Table Rows Here -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I posted the code above - could you show me ...or paste the code...?

Comment: I added some code. Only the `span` and `inline-block` versions (not `float-right`).

Comment: Just noticed your `float:top` ... that's not a thing. See: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Comment: Hi Steve - I tried both the "span" & "inline-block" - neither worked...although the table was located correctly in wordpress editor - when viewing the page as an url ( I am using WAMP) - the table was still below the image...?

Comment: Unless either: (1) wordpress is automatically applying it's own styling or (2) there isn't sufficient horizontal space, either of those should work fine. In case it's the latter you might try reducing the "margin-left" figure.

Comment: Since we're doing styling "inline" there would be no harm in replacing `inline-block;` with `inline-block !important;`. I don't know if it will fix it, however.